# Allowing Untrusted SSL Certificates with Opera browser. Selenium testing (Java)

Tags: java, testing, selenium, ssl-certificate, opera

How can I allow by Selenium WebDriver to accept untrusted certificate on **Opera browser**?
[image: Opera security Issue]

I try to use this code. No positive results

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
WebDriver driver = new OperaDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: I don't know anything but it seems obvious that you should pass the capabilities object somewhere or somehow activate it.

Comment: Yes, of course. I pass the capabilities object to OperaDriver object. I missed row when adding this question. Sorry for this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a custom profile for your opera browser and then set the capability

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.opera();
capabilities.setCapability("opera.profile", new OperaProfile("/path/to/existing/profile"));
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
WebDriver driver = new OperaDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: If I set path to Opera profile like c:\Users\sema\APPData\Roaming\Opera\Opera\ it takes no result

Comment: I found my mistake: capabilities.setCapability("opera.profile",                       new OperaProfile(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/APPData/Roaming/Opera/Opera")); - It works. Thank's a lot! :)

Comment: avoid spaces in the path to the opera profile ;), is likely to fail then (windows)